# find the duplicate element count using array element and array string

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, match

I'm passing an array element and array string in a single function and convert into a string and find duplicate element count.

```js
function count5numbers1(arr, arr1) {
  let m1 = arr.toString().match(/[5]/gi);
  let m2 = arr1.toString().match(/[5]/gi);
  if (m1 === null && m2 != null) {
    return m1 = 0;
  } else if (m1 != null) {
    return m1.length;
  } else if (m2 === null) {
    return m2 = "it's not a number";
  } else {
    return m2.length;
  }
}
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 5, 43], [5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 3, 5], [5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 4, 2], [5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([2, 4, 54, 15], [5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 5, 55, 555], [5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([6, 3, 2, 1], [5]));
console.log(count5numbers1(['notnumber,its a string'], []));
```

But I need to use a single parameter only m1 getting the same result.

The result will be:
1
1
0
2
6
0
it's not a number

Comment: what is the criteria to find duplicates, it is totally dependent on m2.

Comment: Yes, But I need only passing the m1 parameter (arr) get the same result, not needed m2 and arr1(parameter)

Answer (score 0):

```
function count5numbers1(arr) {
  const m1 = arr.toString().match(/[5]/g);
  if (arr.some(e => typeof e != 'number')) {
    return "it's not a number";
  } else if (m1 === null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return m1.length;
  }
}

console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 5, 43]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 3, 5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 4, 2]));
console.log(count5numbers1([2, 4, 54, 15]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 5, 55, 555]));
console.log(count5numbers1([6, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(count5numbers1(['notnumber,its a string']));
```